# VM error: invalid opcode resulting from array operations

Tags: solidity, remix, evm, arrays

pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

```
contract VectorTest {

   /* this runs when the contract is executed */
   function VectorTest() public {
      // initialize the variables        
   }

   // returns an int array by adding to all its elements a scalar value "a"
   function addScalar(int[] self, int a) public pure returns (int[] s) {
      for (uint i = 0; i < self.length; i++)
         s[i] = self[i] + a;
  }

   // returns an int array by adding to all its elements a scalar value "a"
   function addVector(int[] self, int[] melf) public pure returns (int[] s) {
      for (uint i = 0; i < self.length; i++)
         s[i] = self[i] + melf[i];
   }

}
```

I have a very basic VectorTest contract as above. It compiles well in Remix but when I create and try to call its functions with some example values, Remix is giving the error below. E.g., I tried to execute `addScalar([12,12,13], 5)` in this error message:

```
call to browser/BlockChaiNergy01.sol:BlockChaiNergy01.addScalar 
errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode  The constructor should be payable if you send value.
The execution might have thrown.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Onder.

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating the returned array `s`

```
function addScalar(int[] self, int a) public pure returns (int[] s) {

    // Allocate s
    s = new int[](self.length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < self.length; i++)
        s[i] = self[i] + a;
    }
}
```